# Route pattern cannot reference variable more than once. ex. connection/{person}/{person}

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

How does one reference 2 variables with the same pattern.

The idea is simple, what is the connection between person A and person B:

**app/Http/Controllers/ConnectionController.php**

```
class ConnectionController extends Controller {
  public function getDetail($personA, $personB){
    return $personA . $personB;
  }
}
```

**app/Http/routes.php**

```
Route::controller('connection', 'ConnectionController');
```

Was not sufficient to supply a decent URL so I came up with:

**app/Http/routes.php**

```
Route::pattern('person','{a-z}+-{0-9}+');
Route::get('connection/{person}/{person}', 'ConnectionController@getDetail');
```

But it threw an:

```
LogicException in RouteCompiler.php line 102:
Route pattern "/connection/{person}/{person}" cannot reference variable name "person" more than once.
```

How would one achieve this? Quick fix is a duplicate pattern and not use model binding but that just feels wrong.

Comment: What's wrong with `connection/{personA}/{personB}`?

Comment: You can't use the same pattern (name) multiple times in one route. So you have to give them different names and register the same pattern twice. See the question I linked on the least ugly way to do that.

Comment: That's too bad, didn't find the earlier question so forgive me posting a duplicate. Ah well a little less elegance is ok.

Answer (score 2):

```
Route::get('connection/{personA}/{personB}', 'ConnectionController@getDetail');
```

Comment: Posting code isn't an answer, but as lukasgeiter said and your piece of code illustrates it's not possible without a duplicate pattern with a different name.